# Display monitor pivot software

Tags: windows-7, external-display

I've acquired a Samsung SyncMaster 172N which (when originally sold) had the software to pivot it.

I don't have the original disks.  I've tried to use the LG Forte Pivot Softweare which came with my LG pivotable monitor and I also tried the Magic Rotation softtware from the Samsung website; but neither worked...  I also tried teh iRotate software mentioned in [On a dual-monitor setup, how can just one of the two be rotated?](https://superuser.com/questions/53349/on-a-dual-monitor-setup-how-can-just-one-of-the-two-be-rotated)
The iRotate site suggests problems with Intel graphics.

Can anyone point me at any pivoting software that might do the trick?

Windows 7 64-bit.  HP Pavilion dv7 laptop with Intel Mobile HD Graphics